# Git: How To Test after Merging into Production Master Branch

Tags: git, merge, .net-core, devops

We are currently working on Release Version 2. Right now All our part 2 changes work successfully in our Dev, QA, and UAT environments! However, when we merge back into master branch, doesn't the very act of merging or not merging properly/incorrectly cause problems? So how do we solve this issue?

Should we take the deployable artifacts after the Master branch merge, and ensure they work correctly again in QA and UAT?  We have had issues with merging, so trying to figure out the best source control and testing strategy

[image]

Comment: you could compare the `develop` branch to the `master` branch. If they have same contents or *showing* the latest changes on develop, the must be same.

`Merge conflicts`, depending on the resolution, might result to a different content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema, the merge would be a fast-forward one, which means HEAD master would simply reference develop HEAD: its content would be *identical* that what you are merging, because there was no evolution done in master while develop was updated.

Even if you do a `git merge --no-ff`, the resulting merge commit would be identical to develop HEAD.

If the content is *exactly* the same, past tests should stand.